# How to modify an existing (flat) pdf as a form in Java?

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext

Let me start off with saying that I've seen some questions in this regard but nothing actually specifically answering my issue.

Let's say I have a template version of a PDF received by someone else. It's a classic PDF that looks like a form but only one part is editable, the other parts are not because they are being filled in with data from an imported excel sheet. (Sadly I can't show an example)

I've been able to do most in iText 7 but I can't figure out for the life of me if I can change a flat text field into an editable form field, like on image 1.

Image 2 shows checkboxes that I want to make editable as well but I can only change their value within java and even then it only shows a cross, not a checkmark (even if I change the checktype).

[image: just a normal text field that is not editable]

[image: the checkboxes]

It's a bit hard to explain but tl:dr is that I just want to know whether I can edit an existing flat PDF in java or if I have to do so in adobe itself.

Thanks

Comment: If it's indeed a flattened form, the filled in text is now regular page content, just like the labels and other decorations. Probably the fill-ins are in included xobjects, but maybe not. To say whether they still can somehow be recognized as former field values, let alone how to do that, one needs to analyze the actual file.

Comment: Your comment on image 2, on the other hand, sounds like the form is not flattened, at least not the checkboxes in question.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just misusing the term. I can still loop through all the form fields and get.their field names and adjust those in Java but no longer in the PDF itself. As for the checkboxes, their value is only adjustable in Java - states are 'Oui' or 'Non' but no matter the value I enter, the PDF shows a cross in the box (unless when I highlight the checkbox, then a check mark appears from 'behind' the cross). It's a bit annoying as it's someone else's file basically.

Comment: That sounds not like flattened but merely set to read only. But in that case content manipulation should be trivial in itext.

Comment: You have a point there. I'll take a look at that. Unrelated perhaps but is it in any way possible to actually make fields in a flattened PDF interactive again? Apart from actually editing then in Adobe itself?

Comment: *"is it in any way possible to actually make fields in a flattened PDF interactive again?"* - The original form information usually get lost during flattening, i.e. name of the field, exact field position, default appearances, flags, ... Merely the current contents survive, embedded in the regular page content. Thus, you can create fields in the same PDF but they probably would not resemble the original ones very closely.